# Input don’t clear completely when i use backspace in vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I’m using Vue.js with Quasar, when i use backspace on input of type number, the last number to be deleted is always conted, but I need to be able to completely erase this field when I use backspace so it does not disturb a calculation that I do in conjunction with other inputs, can anyone help?

Thank’s.

Comment: Can you please attach some code examples, of how that input looks like and all of listeners on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@nermin thank you for try answer.
I resolved this case using a normally input "", because i noticed that "" of Quasar cause the problem, but i still don't know of why.